# Migrate Sharepoint do a different Server

Tags: 2010, backup, restore

I have a Sharepoint site with a number of web applications (that are relatively large). I need to decommission the Sharepoint site and database servers and install SharePoint from scratch to a new different server.

Should I perform a full farm backup and restore the backup at once? Or should I perform Web application backups and restore the web applications one by one.

What is the recommeded approach / pros and cons please?

Answer (score 0):

A complete migration depends on the components you have in your SharePoint farm.

By components I refer to the following that should account in your migration strategy.

WSP 
Web Config Entries 
Layouts 
folder Site Backups 
Service    Application Backups 
Farm Backups 
Content Database Backups 
 Other customizations

To keep it short here are the scenarios that will help you decide the type of migration you want

- Try for a [complete farm backup and restore](http://www.mssharepointtips.com/tip.asp?id=1040) if the size of the
  databases are not exceeding 50GB. This also takes into account that your present farm and destination farm have similar hardware and topology.
- Go for a [content database attach migration](http://www.mysharepointadventures.com/2011/06/migrate-sites-using-database-attach-method/) if the size of the
  databases are exceeding 50GB.

For performance and stability concerns , personally I would always go for the second option. SQL Backups of database and attach driven restore performs 100 times faster than site backup restore.